# WCF Service on Azure - cores count' was exceeded

Tags: c#, wcf, azure

I am trying to host a cloud service on Windows Azure and I am encountering problems. I have created a WCF Service project and have made a package that I upload on Azure. When I am done uploading the package when i deploy i get this error message **"The subscription policy limit for resource type 'cores count' was exceeded. The limit for resource type 'cores count' is 2 per subscription, the current count is 2, and the requested increment is 1. The long running operation tracking ID was: fb65e4ce8f4e14b99d4f3d55ddd151b9."** Please help with understanding of this error. Does this mean i have too many methods in my service or my methods use a lot of CPU?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have exceeded your soft limit of 20 CPU cores... (i.e the deployed service is requesting the 21st core)
See [HERE](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/arunrakwal/archive/2012/04/11/windows-azure-how-to-increase-cores-per-subscription.aspx) and [HERE](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/69b318c7-daa7-4b52-a39f-6962010ee1a6/subscription-policy-limit-for-resource-type-cores-count)

You need to request an increase. The second link should help you do that

Comment: No, all the cores are added up from all services. You will have to request an increase.

Comment: According to my experiences, after the request, they make the increase in a couple of minutes.